# AutoIt Wait for a Control Element to Appear

Tags: autoit

I'm attempting to automate an application using AutoIt, and I need to wait for a control to appear within the application before the automation can begin. This control loads shortly after the application starts, but it does not change the window title. How do I wait for the control to appear?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get a handle to a control on another GUI you need to use the [AutoIt Window Info Tool](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/au3spy.htm) to identify that control. To get the classname of the control go to the tab "Control" and look up the value for "ClassnameNN". Now you can use this value as I did in the example below.

Of course you need to replace `"Button1"` with the information you got from the AutoIt Info Tool and modify the window titles accordingly.

```
Global $hCtrl = 0, $Waiting = True

; your GUI loop
While (1)
    If $Waiting And WinExists("Title of OtherApp.exe") Then
        $hCtrl = ControlGetHandle("Title of OtherApp.exe", "", "Button1")
        If $hCtrl Then
            ; we got the handle, so the button is there
            ; now do whatever you need to do
            GUICtrlCreateLabel("Button is there!", 10, 10)
            $Waiting = False
        EndIf
    EndIf

    $iMsg = GUIGetMsg()
    Switch $iMsg
        Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
            ExitLoop
    EndSwitch
WEnd
```

Comment: @JohnMoses No the `While (1)` is correct since this is just a snippet and not a full working solution. AutoIt scripts that have an own UI consist of an infinite loop to catch the UI messages and this is what I wanted to show in my script. See: https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/guiref/GUIRef_MessageLoopMode.htm

Comment: @Richard: If you want to test if a control is currently being displayed on the GUI use `GuiControlGetState` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20384147/1879699).